# How do I add a custom PriceFeed from the SDEX exchange

Tags: kelp

On the getting-started page I see sdex listed as an out of the box exchange integration. Is that only used for buying/selling or is there a way to use sdex instead of Kraken to get token price info?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can only place orders on SDEX, but you can fetch data from Kraken, Binance, Poloniex, and Bittrex.

---

It should be relatively very easy for you to create a new price feed that supports this.

Take a look at the [implementation for fixedFeed](https://github.com/lightyeario/kelp/blob/master/plugins/fixedFeed.go), which is only a few lines.

Your implementation would fetch the orderbook for your configured SDEX market and use that data to come up with a *centerPrice* that is returned in the [PriceFeed's GetPrice()](https://github.com/lightyeario/kelp/blob/master/api/priceFeed.go) method.

---

Once you have your new priceFeed implementation, you can add it to the list in the [PriceFeed's *MakePriceFeed()* factory method](https://github.com/lightyeario/kelp/blob/master/plugins/priceFeed.go#L12).

Answer (score 0):

All the current strategies only use the SDEX for buying and selling, and no function is yet present to actually pull the relevant SDEX orderbook.

I'm working on a new strategy that will use the SDEX orderbook data, no ETA yet.